# Python SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, crud

Estoy haciendo un CRUD en python y me sale este error de sintaxis

> Python SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Código:

```
self.btn_guardar = Button(self.ventana, text="Guardar", relief="flat", background="black", foreground="white", command=Lambda:self.guardar()).place(x=750, y=340, width=90)
```

Si alguien sabe donde puede estar el error, muchas gracias.

Comment: Ya lo solucioné, resulto ser Lamba, lo puse lo "L" mayuscula y era con "L" minuscula

Answer (score 0):

En

```
command=Lambda:self.guardar())
```

te sobra un cierra paréntesis.

`Lambda` se escribe con minúsculas (`lambda`)

¿Pará que hacer un lambda sin parámetros?